# Override "Parent" input for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a custom category taxonomy. I am going to have a massive amount of categories, by 90% of them will be child categories. Currently the "Parent" input will display every parent and child category. I would rather have 2 boxes. The firs contains the parent categories and then the box below it will contain the child categories for this parent category. I can work out the logic to make this display and how to process it correctly, but i dont know how to override the existing functionality that is in place.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide example.it is confusing.

Comment: i have added a picture of the form element i want to override

Comment: I guess you (the OP) are looking for something like this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-category-selection-widget/ but only for admin pages?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was hoping to do, but just for this particular taxonomy. the end result is the exact same, its just very difficult when there are so many categories to manage which ones are which. The example given with multiple countries with states as as sub category is the issue im having. so being able to select the country first and then select the state in a different box would be way better.